# The time required to update changes across system

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Being inexperienced, there are many times where I am expecting changes to update shortly, if not immediately, but it doesn't. I end up spending a lot of time troubleshooting to no avail and it miraculously work later. I learned that it takes time for updates to propagate across system.

It has come to a point where many times I am unsure if it is because of the changes not propagated or because I have made a mistake. For example, I didn't know the load balancer takes hours to update and instead of waiting it out, I spent hours troubleshooting. I reckon it is good to have an idea of time required for each product/service to update? I searched the Google's documentation but can't seem to find much information.

I really appreciate any advice for new learner like myself to gauge the time required for certain products and services to update/propagate?

Thanks

Comment: The answer depends on the service and what feature of the service you are changing. Some changes are very fast and some changes take time to deploy. Edit your question to one feature and not generalizations about all services.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks! Very much appreciated. I saw there is a Google's SLA page which links to the SLA's of each products and services. I was wondering if there could be an official documentation for propagation time that lists down the time required to propagate for each products and services. I only see that mentioned in IAM and DNS.